# sort and update a docker-compose.yaml with jq

Tags: json, docker-compose, yaml, jq

This is my docker-compose file:

```
{
  "name": "movies-docker-test",
  "services": {
    "movies-rp": {
      "volumes": [
        {
          "type": "volume",
          "source": "certs",
          "target": "/etc/nginx/certs",
        },
        {
          "type": "bind",
          "source": "/home/nblanchet/jeudi_infra/kubernetes/okd/movies-docker-test/reverse-proxy/wikibase.conf.template",
          "target": "/etc/nginx/templates/wikibase.conf.template"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to update this file so that each `volumes` of each `service` to be sorted by the '.type':

```json
{
  "name": "movies-docker-test",
  "services": {
    "movies-rp": {
      "volumes": [
        {
          "type": "bind",
          "source": "/home/nblanchet/jeudi_infra/kubernetes/okd/movies-docker-test/reverse-proxy/wikibase.conf.template",
          "target": "/etc/nginx/templates/wikibase.conf.template"
        },
        {
          "type": "volume",
          "source": "certs",
          "target": "/etc/nginx/certs"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I managed to do this, but the file is not updated:

```bash
jq  '[.services[].volumes[]?]|sort_by(.type)'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here is what I successfully tested with ''yq'' and the wrapped ''jq'' syntax

```bash
yq '.services|=with_entries(.value|=(select(has("volumes")).volumes |= sort_by((.type)) ))' docker-compose.yml
```

or what I initially did with regular ''jq''

```bash
cat movies.yml | yq eval -ojson |  jq '.services|=with_entries(.value|=(select(has("volumes")).volumes |= sort_by((.type)) ))' | yq -P
```

Answer (score 1):

Given `file`:

```yaml
name: movies-docker-test
services:
  movies-rp:
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: conf
        target: /etc/nginx/conf.d
      - type: volume
        source: certs
        target: /etc/nginx/certs
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: /home/nblanchet/jeudi_infra/kubernetes/okd/movies-docker-test/reverse-proxy/uploadsize.conf
        target: /etc/nginx/conf.d/uploadsize.conf
      - type: bind
        source: /home/nblanchet/jeudi_infra/kubernetes/okd/movies-docker-test/reverse-proxy/wikibase.conf.template
        target: /etc/nginx/templates/wikibase.conf.template
```

then, using `yq 4.40.3`:

```bash
$ yq e 'select(.services.*.volumes | select(tag == "!!seq")|=sort_by(.type))' file
```

```yaml
name: movies-docker-test
services:
  movies-rp:
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /home/nblanchet/jeudi_infra/kubernetes/okd/movies-docker-test/reverse-proxy/uploadsize.conf
        target: /etc/nginx/conf.d/uploadsize.conf
      - type: bind
        source: /home/nblanchet/jeudi_infra/kubernetes/okd/movies-docker-test/reverse-proxy/wikibase.conf.template
        target: /etc/nginx/templates/wikibase.conf.template
      - type: volume
        source: conf
        target: /etc/nginx/conf.d
      - type: volume
        source: certs
        target: /etc/nginx/certs
        read_only: true
```

Comment: ```.*.``` is a good point, but it is not enough when volumes is empty: ```Error: node at path [services.movies-docusaurus.volumes] is not an array (it's a !!null)``` I try to find any equivalent to jq ```?``` to bypass any empty node, but I didn't find such a useful option with jq.